# Perl load line into an array bwteen a range of regexes

Tags: perl

So I have this log file - it is very long.
All I really need to load into an array is the lines from `end\s'\w+'\soutput` to `SUCCESS`.
I want to load the array with the info between these two parameters and pump out the name (example `SENDALLLINES`) the last listed time (example `07:13:56`) and the number (example `399`).
I have no idea how to make the array stop loading at the line containing `SUCCESS` so i can manipulate the info.

```
end 'SENDALLMARKETS' output
07:13:46 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLMARKETS
07:13:46 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0028/PSX_TRMASTER sending spin SENDALLLINES
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLLINES' output:
SUCCESS: Line Range spins sequenced to core stream

end 'SENDALLLINES' output
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLLINES
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh finished sending spins
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/check_tradereporters.sh all trade reporting lines are     connected and logged in
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spins S    ENDALLACCOUNTS SENDALLFIRMS SENDALLAIQ SENDALLSTOCKS SENDALLATTRIBUTABLE
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spin  SENDALLACCOUNTS
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLACCOUNTS' output:
SUCCESS: 399 account record(s) sent

end 'SENDALLACCOUNTS' output
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLACCOUNTS
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:14:01 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spin SENDALLFIRMS
07:14:02 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLFIRMS' output:
SUCCESS: 1488 firm record(s) sent
```

> This is all I have so far

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use warnings;
use strict;

my $LogDir = "/home/shortcasper/perl/work_perl_short/";
my $logFile = "initstart";
my @Log_array;
open ( my $FILE, '<', "$LogDir$logFile") or die ("could not open the file -- $!")
while (<$FILE>) {   
        my $line = $_;
        next if ($line =~ /^$/);
        if ($line =~ /end\s\'\w+\'\soutput/) {
                push (@Log_array, $line);
        }
        foreach my $logLine(@Log_array){
                print $logLine;
        }
        @Log_array = ();
}
```

Comment: use `last` to break loop http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html `last if ($ =~ /SUCCESS/)`

Comment: yeah i tried a last statement - i really need something that will  - read the file, when it hits the regex /end\s\'\w+\'\soutput/ start loading the subsequent lines into an array, when you reach another regex - SUCCESS - stop loading array - process array  and print - erase and do it over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($name, $time, $count);
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^end '(.+?)'/) {
        $name = $1;
    } elsif (/^SUCCESS: (\w+)/) {
        $count = $1;
        $count = 0 if ($count =~ /^\D+$/);
        print "name: $name, time: $time, count: $count\n";
    } else {
        ($time) = $_ =~ /^(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)/;
    }
}

__DATA__
end 'SENDALLMARKETS' output
07:13:46 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLMARKETS
07:13:46 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0028/PSX_TRMASTER sending spin SENDALLLINES
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLLINES' output:
SUCCESS: Line Range spins sequenced to core stream

end 'SENDALLLINES' output
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLLINES
07:13:51 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh finished sending spins
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/check_tradereporters.sh all trade reporting lines are     connected and logged in
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spins S    ENDALLACCOUNTS SENDALLFIRMS SENDALLAIQ SENDALLSTOCKS SENDALLATTRIBUTABLE
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spin  SENDALLACCOUNTS
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLACCOUNTS' output:
SUCCESS: 399 account record(s) sent

end 'SENDALLACCOUNTS' output
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh successfully spun out SENDALLACCOUNTS
07:13:56 /data/noc/startup/send_spins.sh Sleeping for 5 seconds so system can catch up.
07:14:01 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh pats0010/SPINMASTER sending spin SENDALLFIRMS
07:14:02 /data/noc/startup/send_spin.sh start 'SENDALLFIRMS' output:
SUCCESS: 1488 firm record(s) sent
```

**output:**

```
name: SENDALLMARKETS, time: 07:13:51, count: 0
name: SENDALLLINES, time: 07:13:56, count: 399
name: SENDALLACCOUNTS, time: 07:14:02, count: 1488
```

Comment: This works - i mistakenly thought that i would have to load each data set into its own array and then process each array separately  - where as this just goes through the whole fine taking what it needs on the way. Good procedural code.

Answer (score 3):

The [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) is your friend.

Assuming Perl ≥ 5.10, something like

```
while (my $line = readline $FILE) {
    if ($line =~ /end\s'(\w+)'\soutput/ ... $line =~ /SUCCESS/) {
        $name //= $1;
        push @lines, $line;
    } elsif (defined $name) {
        say "Got $#lines for $name";
        undef $name;
        @lines = ();
    }
}
```

Comment: The range operator works - I never thought to use it in this way. I never used 'say' (I looked it up - it appends a newline at the end.) - I don't understand the $name //= part. I know the one is the capture from the regex. Replacing the "//=" with just the "=" but it does not work.  i have never seen the double backslash before the assignment operator. is there a perl doc on it?